# How to divide 8 channels into individual channel, and let them go to a pipe by alsa plugin

Tags: c, linux, plugins, alsa

My audio go through a pipe by alsa plugin, and this is my asound.conf setting.

```
pcm.plug_0 {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm rate48000Hz
        channels 8
    }
}

pcm.rate48000Hz {
    type rate
    slave {
        pcm writeFile
        format S16_LE
        rate 48000
    }
}

pcm.writeFile {
    type file
    slave.pcm null
    file "/tmp/fifo"
    format "raw"
}
```

The audio consists of 8 channels.
I want them divide into individual channel, and let them go to the pipe.

I try to change my code,

```
pcm.ch1 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1234
    slave {
        pcm plug_0
        rate 48000
        channels 8
    }
    bindings.0 1
}

pcm.ch2 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1234
    slave {
        pcm plug_0
        rate 48000
        channels 8
    }
    bindings.0 2
}

pcm.ch3 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1234
    slave {
        pcm plug_0
        rate 48000
        channels 8
    }
    bindings.0 3
}

pcm.plug_0{
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm rate48000Hz
        channels 8
    }
}

pcm.rate48000Hz {
    type rate
    slave {
        pcm writeFile
        format S16_LE
        rate 48000
    }
}

pcm.writeFile {
    type file
    slave.pcm null
    file "/tmp/fifo"
    format "raw"
}
```

And I shell the cmd

```
aplay -Dch1 xxx.wav
```

it response

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1817:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid type 'null' for slave PCM

aplay: main:828: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

then I comment out `slave.pcm null`

and shell `aplay -Dch1 xxx.wav` again

it response

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1817:(_snd_pcm_direct_get_slave_ipc_offset) Invalid type 'file' for slave PCM

aplay: main:828: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

Is there any idea can solve this problem ?

Comment: `dshare` works only with `hw` slave devices. Try creating an actual kernel device with the `snd-aloop` driver.